# How do I implement and use eyecon's bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I visited [Eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and downloaded the datepicker. I got three folders. 'css', 'js' and 'less'. I have included the bootstrap-datepicker.js and the latest jquery.js and linked the .css in the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css">


    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="well">
            <!--What should I enter here and where/how do I call the function?-->
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As one can see, I'm already working with the bootstrap library and have therefore also included that.

My question now is: how do I implement and call the date picker function?

Comment: And what tha heck is that .less in the 'less' folder? :)

Comment: [LESS is magic ;)](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: aha, that looks awesome :)

Comment: Yup. You could also take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$('element').datepicker();` where `element` is some class, id etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/6kk3k/1/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```