# Why this Bootstrap datepicker won't update the input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a datepicker form a Bootstrap template. I already implemented a datepicker using jQuery 1.9 version, but it doesn't work in my job web app, that currently runs on jQuery 1.8. The template that I'm trying to emulate, is the very same template used in the company project should, if I get this one to work, I will surely do the same with the actual project.

You can see an example of the datepicker from the template, here: http://www.f5exe.com/204/form-elements.html

Now, here's come the problem. I haven't touched that template nor any code. If you notice, the datepicker seems to work, but if you choose a date, it doesn't update the input value!!! What could be possible wrong with it?

You can check the original files of the templates here:

http://1drv.ms/MOe0dd (Skydrive link)

I don't see anything wrong in the js. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please post relevant code, rather than a zip of the whole site.

I haven't looked at your code, but are you explicitly updating the datepicker?

Try:

```
var ID = $("#myDatePickerID");

ID.datepicker({
    format : 'mm-dd-yyyy',
});

 ID.on('changeDate', function(e){
   IS.val(e.target.value);
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to touch the code because this template suppose to work as is. For example, the timepicker, single select and select-deselect features woks well. I will implement your logic though.

Comment: That is understandable. I see the timepicker is functioning correctly. Is this a purchased template? If you haven't modified the code and it isn't functioning you should post a bug report with the dev.

Comment: Yes, it is a purchased template, but that was like a year and half though. I'm trying to implement yet another datepicker from Eyecom, and it doesn't seems to work either, although in the example at http://jsfiddle.net/6kk3k/1/ it work's well. I'm following the instructions in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935718/how-do-i-implement-and-use-eyecons-bootstrap-datepicker with no avail. What  can I be doing wrong? I can see my input box but when I click it, no  datepicker is shown.